# Overwrite php.ini settings on IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, web-config

I tried to make an PHP upload form on a windows server, but the upload didn't work because there's no temporary directory. I checked which value is set for the `upload_temp_dir` and `phpinfo()` says `"no value"`.

Is it possible to overwrite the php.ini settings for `upload_tmp_dir` on a IIS? I have no access to the php.ini file. I looked for a possibility to change it with help of a web.config file, but with no result.

Comment: do you have root access/admin account to the server?

Comment: no, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the function
`init_set()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 0):

You can change PHP config by creating a ".user.ini" file. For example, the following will enable the short open tag for your site:

> short_open_tag = On

Upload the file to the root directory of your site.

- If the PHP version is 5.3 or 5.6 the file name is:  user.ini
- For any other PHP version the file name is:  .user.ini